# JQuery match different id with the last same number

Tags: html, jquery

I have example HTML code like this:

```
    <select id="label_1">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <select id="item_1">
        <option></option>
    </select>

    <select id="label_2">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <select id="item_2">
        <option></option>
    </select>
```

How do I write jQuery code to match the label and item id with the same number?

```
    if($("#label_" + [/[0-9]+$/]) == $("#item_" + [/[0-9]+$/])) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: You need to make a parent element of each of the pair of item and label and give the parent same class for every pair. Now you will be able to access, say for example ParentElement[0] and you will know that first label and first item are nested inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the *label* elements first and then iterate them to find the matching *item* elements

```js
$("select[id^='label_']").each((_, label) => {
  const idSuffix = label.id.split("_").pop();
  const item = $(`#item_${idSuffix}`);

  // now you have both `label` and `item`
});
```

---

The vanilla JS version isn't much different

```js
document.querySelectorAll("select[id^='label_']").forEach((label) => {
  const idSuffix = label.id.split("_").pop();
  const item = document.getElementById(`item_${idSuffix}`);

  // now you have both `label` and `item`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do one time : return false

```js
$.each($("select[id^= 'label_']"), function(){
  let num = this.id.replace('label_', '')
  let equal = $(this).value ===  $("#item_" + num).value
  if(equal) {
    // do something
    
    // if you want to run one times ( return false)
    return false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="label_1">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>
<select id="item_1">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>

<select id="label_2">
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
<select id="item_2">
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
```